# A book with heuristics or general techniques used in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, metric-spaces, book-recommendation

I have been looking for a book with some good heuristics for real analysis and point set topology. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Simmons's *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis*, found [here](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/Introduction_To_Topology_And_Modern_Anal.html?id=0e5Xq3fGnAgC&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: This book is well known both for its pedagogical soundness and clarity, and for its combination of topology and analysis. (The question was really broad, so I just wrote the name of a good book.)